# PHP show logged-in username on the top of every page

Tags: php

I'm building a College blackboard type app and I have a php file that handles authorization. I use javascript ajax post to send data to server and intermediate php to echo the response back. Then i redirect to the home page.

I can't figure out how to save the username from initial page and display to the top right of the redirected page `logged in as 'username'`.

I've tried things like

```
<!-- main.php -->  
<?php session_start(); $_SESSION['u-name'] = $_POST['ucid'];?>
```

Then inside other file

```
include 'main.php'
echo $_SESSION['id'];
```

Didn't work.

Comment: Did you call `session_start()` on EVERY page request you are doing?

Comment: Your question is hard to read and missing relevant code extracts...

Answer (score 2):

inside other file it should be

```
include 'main.php'
echo $_SESSION['u-name']; 
            //--^^^^^^---here
```

cause your setting the session to `u-name` and not `id`

Comment: ok so i have a login page with a id/password(login.php) `<html> <body> <form id="w.e" input type= "login"></form></body></html>` I use ajax to post that server ` $.ajax({ 
         cache: false,
         type: 'POST',              
         url:'local.php',
         dataType: 'json',
         data: JSON.stringify(mock_object),
         success: function (response) {
             var your_object = response;
             $(document.body).append(JSON.stringify(your_object)); ** THEN REDIRECT TO LOGGED IN PAGE(logged_in.php)` I need inside of logged_in.php todisplay current user logged in..

Answer (score 0):

If the 'ucid' in your example is the username, you can use the following codes:

**Main.php**

```
<?php 
    session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['ucid'])) { // Added check to make sure it does not empty the session variable if there is no post (because you include this on every page)
        $_SESSION['u-name'] = $_POST['ucid'];
    }
?>
```

**Other file**

```
<?php
    include 'main.php';
    echo $_SESSION['u-name'];
?>
```